# Firebase analytics AppMeasurement not enabled

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

I have followed all the instructions for integrating Firebase analytics correctly in my project. But when I enable debug logging to make sure the events are being sent (using instructions from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/)) I see

```
E/FA      ( 3556): AppMeasurementReceiver not registered/enabled
E/FA      ( 3556): AppMeasurementService not registered/enabled
E/FA      ( 3556): Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
```

and obviously the events are not being sent.

Again I have followed all the instructions .

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It turns out that Firebase Library has an Android Manifest file in which it defines these nodes:

```
 <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
     android:enabled="true"
     android:exported="false"/>

 <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
     android:enabled="true">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.UPLOAD" />
     </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

based on [AppMeasurementService](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurementService) and [AppMeasurementReceiver](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurementReceiver)

which are needed for analytics to work and my problem was that I was replacing all the library nodes with `<tools:node=”replace”>` in my Android Manifest which in turn ignored the needed nodes for analytics lib.

Removing `<tools:node=”replace”>` and replacing my conflicts specifically solved my problem.

Comment: this is it! Even Firebase customer service could not figure out what was wrong in my project settings; and they spent weeks asking questions.
How did you figure it out?

Comment: I'm glad it helped you, it took me a while to figure it out as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you made my day, I was facing same issue from 2 days and was not able to resolve the issue, your solution worked for me.

Comment: I was struggling with this for days! Thank you very much for your time! You save so much time for me!

Comment: Thank you for saving my sanity removing this and adding `tools:node="replace"` to my `com.facebook.FacebookActivity` fixed it for me

Comment: what is more important is focusing on <tools:node=”replace”> and resolve conflicts.

Answer (score 16):

Make sure you set mata data at the manifest `firebase_analytics_collection_enabled` to be `true`

```
<meta-data
     android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
     android:value="true" />
```

Comment: Worked for me @ Android Studio 3.6.3 ; Pixel 3 API 29 Emulator.

Comment: I don't remember which tutorial or code snipped I copied, or what I thought when I did this, but turns out, I added this `meta-data` with value `false`, I removed that `meta-data` and it worked! And it took me days to look for answers! I was checking both build.gradle, proguard, multiple mulitple times! And tried many things, but my issue was right infront of me all this time!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, a library I was using was including Firebase but explictly disabling analytics [in their manifest](https://github.com/Microsoft/EmbeddedSocial-Android-SDK/issues/118).

So I had to override that setting in my `AndroidManifest.xml` to enable analytics with the following (just before the `</application>` tag):

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated" android:value="false"
                   tools:replace="android:value"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The above accepted answer got outdated. `AppMeasurementService` and `AppMeasurementReciver` is deprectaed and adding it in manifest wont be useful.

Now they support Firebase analytics and recommend to use

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'`

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked for me so I'm posting this because this issue was awfully annoying.

In my case, the problem was a disguised version mismatch. It went away when I updated the `android:versionName` in my manifest to the newest release build's version.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.your.package"
    android:versionCode="100"
    android:versionName="4.0.0"> <!-- Update this -->

...
```