# AppMeasurementReceiver not registered/enabled and AppMeasurementService not registered not enabled

Tags: android

### **Hey guys, i know this might question might have been asked before, I really need some help. I keep getting this 'App_Measurement_Receiver' not registered/enabled, 'App_Measurement_Service' not enabled. I cant seem to login to my App. what might be the problem guys and how may i go about it? **

```
08-19 21:13:50.826 3019-3255/? E/FA: 'AppMeasurementReceiver' not registered/enabled
08-19 21:13:50.827 3019-3255/? E/FA: 'AppMeasurementService' not registered/enabled
08-19 21:13:50.827 3019-3255/? E/FA: Uploading is not possible. App
measurement disabled
```

** Android manifest file**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hushtagstudios.towme">

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:parentActivityName=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.hushtagstudios.towme.SplashActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Register"
            android:label="@string/Register"
            android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.hushtagstudios.towme.LoginActivity" />
            </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/Let_us_help_activity_title"
            android:theme="@style/MyAppStyleTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PaymentNav"
            android:label="@string/Payment"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HistoryNav"
            android:label="@string/menu_history"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".NotificationNav"
            android:label="@string/menu_Notifications"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ShareNav"
            android:label="@string/share"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HelpNav"
            android:label="@string/how_can_we_assist_you"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsNav"
            android:label="@string/menu_Settings"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AboutNav"
            android:label="@string/menu_about"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AddPaymentMethod"
            android:label="@string/add_payment_method"
            android:parentActivityName=".PaymentNav"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CreditCardNav"
            android:label="@string/add_payment_method"
            android:parentActivityName=".AddPaymentMethod"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".TripHelp"
            android:label="@string/select_trip"
            android:parentActivityName=".HelpNav"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AccountPaymentOptions"
            android:label="@string/Account_and_payments"
            android:parentActivityName=".HelpNav"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HowToUseTowMe"
            android:label="@string/How_to_use_tow_me"
            android:parentActivityName=".HelpNav"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SigningUpHelp"
            android:label="@string/signing_up_to_tow_me"
            android:parentActivityName=".HelpNav"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MoreHelp"
            android:label="@string/More"
            android:parentActivityName=".HelpNav"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CantSignIn"
            android:label="@string/menu_user_accountandpayment_issue1"
            android:parentActivityName=".AccountPaymentOptions"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CantUpdateMobile"
            android:label="@string/menu_user_accountandpayment_issue2"
            android:parentActivityName=".AccountPaymentOptions"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PaymentOptions"
            android:label="@string/menu_user_accountandpayment_issue3"
            android:parentActivityName=".AccountPaymentOptions"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AccountPaymentSettingsHelp"
            android:label="@string/menu_user_accountandpayment_issue4"
            android:parentActivityName=".AccountPaymentOptions"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PromosCreditsHelp"
            android:label="@string/menu_user_accountandpayment_issue5"
            android:parentActivityName=".AccountPaymentOptions"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".UknownChargeHelp"
            android:label="@string/menu_user_accountandpayment_issue6"
            android:parentActivityName=".AccountPaymentOptions"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CantSignInIssue1"
            android:label="@string/menu_user_cant_sign_in_issue1"
            android:parentActivityName=".CantSignIn"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CantSignInIssue2"
            android:label="@string/menu_user_cant_sign_in_issue2"
            android:parentActivityName=".CantSignIn"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CantSignIssue4"
            android:label="@string/mennu_user_cant_sign_in_issue4"
            android:parentActivityName=".CantSignIn"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CantSignInIssue3"
            android:label="@string/menu_user_cant_sign_in_issue3"
            android:parentActivityName=".CantSignIn"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CantSignInIssue5"
            android:label="@string/mennu_user_cant_sign_in_issue5"
            android:parentActivityName=".CantSignIn"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CantSignInIssue6"
            android:label="@string/mennu_user_cant_sign_in_issue6"
            android:parentActivityName=".CantSignIn"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.class file**

```
package com.hushtagstudios.towme;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import at.markushi.ui.CircleButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private NavigationView navigationView = null;
    private CircleButton cbBattery;
    private CircleButton cbAcc;
    private CircleButton cbFlatTire;
    private CircleButton cbFuel;
    private CircleButton cbMechanical;
    private CircleButton cbInsurance;
    private CircleButton cbLocked;
    private CircleButton cbStuckInDitch;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.nav_action);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.mDrawerLayout);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

         navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
         navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        cbBattery = (CircleButton)findViewById(R.id.cbBattery);
        cbBattery.setOnClickListener(this);
        cbAcc = (CircleButton)findViewById(R.id.cbAcc);
        cbAcc.setOnClickListener(this);
        cbFlatTire = (CircleButton)findViewById(R.id.cbFlatTire);
        cbFlatTire.setOnClickListener(this);
        cbFuel = (CircleButton)findViewById(R.id.cbFuel);
        cbFuel.setOnClickListener(this);
        cbInsurance =(CircleButton)findViewById(R.id.cbInsurance);
        cbInsurance.setOnClickListener(this);
        cbLocked = (CircleButton)findViewById(R.id.cbLocked);
        cbLocked.setOnClickListener(this);
        cbMechanical = (CircleButton)findViewById(R.id.cbMechanical);
        cbMechanical.setOnClickListener(this);
        cbStuckInDitch = (CircleButton)findViewById(R.id.cbStuckInDitch);
        cbStuckInDitch.setOnClickListener(this);


    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.mDrawerLayout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public  boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

        if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
    @SuppressWarnings("StatementsWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_payment) {

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PaymentNav.class));

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_history) {

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HistoryNav.class));

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_notifications) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationNav.class));

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShareNav.class));


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_help) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HelpNav.class));


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsNav.class));


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutNav.class));


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.mDrawerLayout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.cbBattery:
                break;

            case R.id.cbAcc:
                break;

            case R.id.cbFlatTire:
                break;

            case R.id.cbFuel:
                break;

            case R.id.cbInsurance:
                break;

            case R.id.cbLocked:
                break;

            case R.id.cbMechanical:
                break;

            case R.id.cbStuckInDitch:
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

** LoginActivity.class file **

```
package com.hushtagstudios.towme;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import at.markushi.ui.CircleButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private NavigationView navigationView = null;
    private CircleButton cbBattery;
    private CircleButton cbAcc;
    private CircleButton cbFlatTire;
    private CircleButton cbFuel;
    private CircleButton cbMechanical;
    private CircleButton cbInsurance;
    private CircleButton cbLocked;
    private CircleButton cbStuckInDitch;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.nav_action);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.mDrawerLayout);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

         navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
         navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        cbBattery = (CircleButton)findViewById(R.id.cbBattery);
        cbBattery.setOnClickListener(this);
        cbAcc = (CircleButton)findViewById(R.id.cbAcc);
        cbAcc.setOnClickListener(this);
        cbFlatTire = (CircleButton)findViewById(R.id.cbFlatTire);
        cbFlatTire.setOnClickListener(this);
        cbFuel = (CircleButton)findViewById(R.id.cbFuel);
        cbFuel.setOnClickListener(this);
        cbInsurance =(CircleButton)findViewById(R.id.cbInsurance);
        cbInsurance.setOnClickListener(this);
        cbLocked = (CircleButton)findViewById(R.id.cbLocked);
        cbLocked.setOnClickListener(this);
        cbMechanical = (CircleButton)findViewById(R.id.cbMechanical);
        cbMechanical.setOnClickListener(this);
        cbStuckInDitch = (CircleButton)findViewById(R.id.cbStuckInDitch);
        cbStuckInDitch.setOnClickListener(this);


    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.mDrawerLayout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public  boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

        if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
    @SuppressWarnings("StatementsWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_payment) {

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PaymentNav.class));

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_history) {

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HistoryNav.class));

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_notifications) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationNav.class));

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShareNav.class));


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_help) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HelpNav.class));


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsNav.class));


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutNav.class));


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.mDrawerLayout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.cbBattery:
                break;

            case R.id.cbAcc:
                break;

            case R.id.cbFlatTire:
                break;

            case R.id.cbFuel:
                break;

            case R.id.cbInsurance:
                break;

            case R.id.cbLocked:
                break;

            case R.id.cbMechanical:
                break;

            case R.id.cbStuckInDitch:
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase analytics AppMeasurement not enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39480272/firebase-analytics-appmeasurement-not-enabled)

Comment: i have tried the above nothing is changing?

Answer (score -1):

Disable Firebase .
check this dropdown :

[image]

Also additionally 
in my case that  was simple. I had BroadcastReciever class declared within a java file. It wasnt envolved into the code, like a garbage test code. The problem started show that  "AppMeasurementReceiver not registered/enabled" right after I have removed useless reciever node in manifest. So finally I removed that class switched processes in second (dropdown) window from left side of Android Monitor and it started work as usually.